# Proper way to name elements in Visuabl Basic. EX: frmMain

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for a reference that tells you the proper way to name form elements in Visual Basic.

EX: 
btnGo
frmMain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Visual Basic Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx) on MSDN.

As far as [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), as in your examples, this is discouraged. The type of the object doesn't need to be reflected in the variable name. It is better to give your variables good descriptive names for *what* they represent.

So, instead of `btnGo`, call it `GoToPage`. Instead of `frmMain`, call it `CustomerDetails`. Use a descriptive name for the *function* of the control.